# How to check a Particular Radio Box in a "Group" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio box group and I need to select a given radio box using javascript as in the following case, I have to check option with value D3

```
<input type="radio" name="day" id="day" value="D1" />D1
<input type="radio" name="day" id="day" value="D2" />D2
<input type="radio" name="day" id="day" value="D3" />D3
<input type="radio" name="day" id="day" value="D4" />D4
```

How can the third option for example be checked?

Comment: are you sure they all share the same name and id?

Comment: If they all have the same name , why not using `radio`?
checkbox groups have created for multi-selecting.

Comment: By having the same id's they form a group. AM I doing it wrong?

Comment: sorry my bad. It is radio. I am going to edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure putting this radio group in a form and change the `theNameOfTheForm` to your form's name.

```
<form name="theNameOfTheForm">
..
..
..
</form>
```

The java-script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function select_radio_value(theValue)
{
for (var i=0; i < document.theNameOfTheForm.day.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.theNameOfTheForm.day[i].value == theValue)
      {
         document.theNameOfTheForm.day[i].checked = true;
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Now you can use it as a js function on any event. for instance:

```
<input type='button' name='c3' value='Click Here to check the D3 radio' onClick="javascript:select_radio_value('D3')">
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid any loops. Anyways, it works & thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd use document.getElementById('day').val or jQuery('#day').val(). That is, if they have different ids. If they share the id, I'm not sure you can with document.getElementById since it assumes that the ids are different, but perhaps

```
jQuery('#day')[3].val()
```

could work, because jQuery actually returns an array of elements that match the criteia

Comment: In my case, I don't know the index of the option i want to select. I just know the value i.e. D1 or D4 or N1 or N2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unique `ID` from each of the checkboxes. You should only have ONE unique `ID` on a page.

In JavaScript, access the third checkbox in this group with the following and set it to `checked`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputs[2].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

OR, you can simply add `checked=checked` to your HTML.

Comment: My form has more <input> fields than I have shown in the example. It does not seem to be the proper method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectRadio(toBeSelectedRadioIndex)
{
    var radioElements = document.getElementById('day');
    radioElements[toBeSelectedRadioIndex].checked = true;
}
```

In many cases you need to have Id names different for your elements.
You can then give them same name and use getElementsByTagName instead.
The the code will look like...

```
function selectRadio(toBeSelectedRadioIndex)
{
    var radioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('day');
    radioElements[toBeSelectedRadioIndex].checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the index. I know the value. I need to check the box based on the value provided and not the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the radio buttons different ids and then do the following :

```
d3.select("input#thirdRadio").property("checked", "true");
```